# What is the maximum database size in Titanium?

Tags: titanium

What is the maximum database size? Is there a chart that shows maximum database size across different devices? Can you store a pre-populated database on an SD card and plug that into the device and read that database with titanium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no limit (as far as I know besides SQL limits) on the size of a database except available storage on device, *but* obviously your app wont really function responsively  if you have a ridiculous (a million rows) amount of data stored on the device.
2. The chart would just be comparing phone flash memory.
3. Probably, but there hasn't been a lot of success. Check [here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/118474/create-folder-on-sdcard---android), and [here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/122888/attach-a-sqlite-db-from-sd-card) and [here](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-10223).